# How do you pronounce the word "via"?

Tags: pronunciation

There are two pronunciations of "via".

1. ˈvaɪə
2. ˈviːə

What's the difference?

Answer (score -1):

None. The first one sounds a bit more casual, the second one a notch more formal.

Comment: It's an interesting idea. I know it's hard to represent pronunciations in writing, but could you offer any examples or other evidence to support your claim? In particular, I think you'd need to show *the same person* using different pronunciations in different circumstances.